# r data transform separate columns

Tags: r, transform, reshape, dplyr

I have a dataset with two columns three columns. The third column has date value mixed with some strings.

```
 ID     Col1        Value
 123    Start.Date  2011-06-18
 123    Stem        A1
 123    Stem_1      A6
 123    Stem_2      NA
 321    Start.Date  2014-08-05
 321    Stem        C1
 321    Stem_1      C4
 321    Stem_2      NA
 677    Start.Date  NA
 677    Stem        NA
 677    Stem_1      NA
 677    Stem_2      NA
```

How can I separate out the dates and store them in a different column like this ?

```
 ID     Col1        Value       Start.Date
 123    Stem        A1          2011-06-18 
 123    Stem_1      A6          2011-06-18
 123    Stem_2      NA          2011-06-18 
 321    Stem        C1          2014-08-05
 321    Stem_1      C4          2014-08-05
 321    Stem_2      NA          2014-08-05
 677    Stem        NA          NA
 677    Stem_1      NA          NA
 677    Stem_2      NA          NA
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column in the data which has value from `Value` column wehre `Col1 = 'Start.Date'` or `NA` otherwise. For each `ID` we can fill the `NA` value from the previous dates and remove the rows with `'Start.Date'`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Start.Date = as.Date(replace(Value, Col1 != 'Start.Date', NA))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  fill(Start.Date) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(Col1 != 'Start.Date')

#    ID Col1   Value Start.Date
#  <int> <chr>  <chr> <date>    
#1   123 Stem   A1    2011-06-18
#2   123 Stem_1 A6    2011-06-18
#3   123 Stem_2 NA    2011-06-18
#4   321 Stem   C1    2014-08-05
#5   321 Stem_1 C4    2014-08-05
#6   321 Stem_2 NA    2014-08-05
#7   677 Stem   NA    NA        
#8   677 Stem_1 NA    NA        
#9   677 Stem_2 NA    NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 321L, 321L, 321L, 
321L, 677L, 677L, 677L, 677L), Col1 = c("Start.Date", "Stem", 
"Stem_1", "Stem_2", "Start.Date", "Stem", "Stem_1", "Stem_2", 
"Start.Date", "Stem", "Stem_1", "Stem_2"), Value = c("2011-06-18", 
"A1", "A6", NA, "2014-08-05", "C1", "C4", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Ronak Shah, your solution is missing one thing. After moving the dates to separate column, the rows with `Start.Date` should be removed.

Comment: You are right, I missed that. I have updated the answer to include that @RiloDinga

Comment: that was perfect. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution based solely on `tidyr`:

```
df %>% pivot_wider(ID, names_from =  Col1, values_from = Value ) %>%
  pivot_longer(c("Stem", "Stem_1", "Stem_2"), names_to = "Col1", values_to = "Value")
```

Comment: i gettting a warning message `Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates ` and the results are goobledegoo with some list values  when I try this approach on a larger dataset

Comment: @RiloDinga The warning message is due to duplicate `Col1` values for a particular `ID` and thus columns become list-column.  For example, `ID = 999` has two `Stem_1` values.  Assuming that each ID has only one `Start.Date`,  `%>% unnest(cols = c(Start.Date, Value))`  should be added at the end.